# Include a text message in ASSERT?

Tags: abap, assert

I have an ABAP line like this:

```
assert ( cond = 'x' ).
```

The caller of this RFC function gets a meaningless message that some assertion failed and I would like to supply an additional explanatory text. This way I can easily find the matching line if the customer send me the error message.

How to do this the most simple way in ABAP?

**Update**: This question focused on `assert`, but this is the wrong track in ABAP, I wrote a new and better question here: [Raise Exception with custom message in ABAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661797/raise-exception-with-custom-message-in-abap)

Comment: With RFC, you don't have lots of choices available: either a classic exception or a parameter containing the text.

Comment: @SandraRossi how does the most simple way to raise an exception look like? (remeber nobody is ever going to catch the exception)

Comment: @SandraRossi I wrote a new question (including my background context) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661797/raise-exception-with-custom-message-in-abap

Answer (score 1):

I found that this works:

```
message my_string_var type 'E'.
```

It is not an assertion, but it does what I want: It terminates the function and displays my variable.

You can use this handy method to serialize variables, to see their internals. Here variable `foo_var` gets serialized to json:

```
MESSAGE |Error foo_var: | && 
     /ui2/cl_json=>serialize( data = foo_var 
     pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-low_case ) TYPE 'E'.
```

Comment: When it's used in a [RFC context, MESSAGE](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_message_rfc.htm) has a tricky impact, it should only be used when it's called via a SAP GUI dialog. Otherwise it just short dumps. So, to be avoided in RFC. Prefer classic exceptions or a parameter containing the text.

Comment: @SandraRossi I use this only for debugging, not in production. Or it there a better way (for debugging)?

Comment: I target my answers to people who will search for answers in the future, so I want to warn that it should not be used in RFC-enabled function modules from my point of view as a **rule-of-thumb** (there are arguments to use it too). Personally, I never write temporary code; I use test classes or ASSERT or ASSERT with a checkpoint group that you may activate in logging mode (or debugger but you don't like it) when needed `ASSERT ID zcheckpointgroup FIELDS f1 f2 ... CONDITION <logexp>.` (transaction code SAAB). SAP use them extensively.

Answer (score 1):

From the [SAP Documentation](http://saphelp.ucc.ovgu.de/NW750/EN/73/a417fb3e80462980dd4caf0a653041/frameset.htm):

> All methods have the optional import parameters MSG, LEVEL, and QUIT with the same meaning:
>
> - MSG (type: CSEQUENCE) contains (if available) a text that describes the error in more detail

So you can easily add texts to your assertions like this:

```
TRY.
 cut->divide_by_zero( denominator = 1).
CATCH cx_sy_zerodivide.
ENDTRY.

cl_abap_unit_assert=>fail( msg = 'CX_SY_ZERODIVIDE not raised'
                           level = if_aunit_constants=>critical ).
```

Answer (score 0):

assert function designed for using in test classes, details are [here](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapassert.htm). I think it is not suitable using in normal codes. You can use **check** for same functionality but it is not return any message. Raising exceptions in function or class is proper way.

You can return OK and MESSAGE variable for if you don't want to use exceptions. In start of your method/function set OK as empty and MESSAGE such as "there is an error" message. Update message manually before doing something. At the end clear message and set X to MESSAGE.

```
function ZMKY_TEST.
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Local Interface:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(COND) TYPE  C
*"  EXPORTING
*"     REFERENCE(OK) TYPE  C
*"     REFERENCE(MESSAGE) TYPE  STRING
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------

  clear: OK, MESSAGE.
  MESSAGE = 'There is an error.'

  MESSAGE = 'COND not equal to X'.
  check COND = 'X'.

  clear: MESSAGE.
  OK = 'X'.

endfunction.
```

Comment: For me the proper way is the way which needs few characters. In this case there will never be code which tries to catch/handle the exception. I just want to terminate the rfc call and give the caller a meaningful (custom) error message. Assert and check can't do this and a class based exception feels to complicated. I am still searching for a simple solution.

Comment: No, "ASSERT" is NOT designed for using in test classes, it's to be used in the productive code when there are "tautologies" (Always true/or contradictions for false), for instance `IF itab IS NOT INITIAL read table itab index 1 assert sy-subrc = 0` (it would be better to test nothing here because obvious, assert is well suited for less obvious tautologies). If the situation happens, it means that there's a programming error, and it's better to stop when it's detected early. It should never be used inside an API for ensuring input parameters are passed the right way, use exceptions instead...

Comment: @guettli I added another approach to my answer.

Comment: Agree with Sandra. ASSERT is NOT associated purely with test classes, it is misleading.

Comment: @mkysoft I wrote a new question (including my background context) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661797/raise-exception-with-custom-message-in-abap